# Swift SpriteKit enumerateChildNodesWithName

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite

Can someone help?
When I enumerateChildNodesWithName, I get the nodes returned
and I can do a println as below.   Seems to work fine.
But if I try to get a property of the node such as
println(thisSprite.position) it fails to build.
What am I doing wring?

```
class func move(scene: SKScene ){
    scene.enumerateChildNodesWithName("anode", usingBlock: {(thisSprite ) in
        println(thisSprite)
        })
}
```

Comment: What is the exact build error that you see?

Comment: Looks like an issue with your closure declaration. Check out the duplicate question for some hints.